# command line of process without admin permission in windows

Tags: batch-file

I want to get command line of a process without admin permission.

I tried

```
WMIC PROCESS WHERE "NAME='NAME.EXE'" GET COMMANDLINE
```

But I can't get anything, all I did needs admin right.

How can I get process command-line without no permission, not using C#?

Is there another way to get process command line, not using wmi, C#, powerShell?

Comment: If Microsoft have determined that the information is only available with elevation or as a particular user or group, then you'll need to perform the task accordingly.

Comment: I see.. Thanks a lot! xD